# keyof with a property of an `as const`

Tags: typescript

I have this object:

```
const args = {
  "a": {"name": "A"},
  "b": {"name": "Some B"},
  "c": {"name": "And a C"},
  "d": {"name": "And a D"},
} as const;
```

which I'm using in a function like

```
const mainUse(s: string) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(args, s)) {
    return otherFunction(args[s].name);
  } else {
    throw new Error("unknown key: " + s);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to type-annotate `otherFunction()` the way I would want? Something like this:

```
otherFunction(s: (keyof typeof args).map(a => a.name))
```

Do I have to create a separate object just to use it in my type annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
type ArgsName = typeof args[keyof typeof args]['name']
```

This will give you a union over the `name` props of the values in `args`:

> type ArgsName = "A" | "Some B" | "And a C" | "And a D"

[in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwOYRgXhgbwFAxgIjnwC4t8w4BbAUxIIEF8BfAGlwICM7NyrbT8AZRA0YAIWZs8+YN1406+emAAm8GAGFJ7fCrkUFA5WrgwAItqbxUoSFADc2bADMArmGBQAluBhew9MgQABQQxNAI-kgAlKSoXqgA1tQAniDOMFApAA7U6fBBOHgI1FCuCGAw8ZWIKNhMTrbQMJRw-gCqENToMG4e3uChcVCRYDFY7F4Zwf6BKKHR0RN4xaXllSBQABbUCABi7p4+YMG1EADaEAC6AHQG1NGOeFbUADZdyyvbCCAA7jBgaj-ACiCB+CGC+HciTAf0qyRSAhgAGoqo92A0GtgsrkYHMIAA5Pg9HF5DJnc4I-Kk-JnK7nADk9wZV2wKmowFeiG6fSOvk2O32hwGJzCeKCRJosXgYBS2CAA)

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic for that :

```
const args = {
  "a": {"name": "A"},
  "b": {"name": "Some B"},
  "c": {"name": "And a C"},
  "d": {"name": "And a D"},
} as const;

const mainUse = (s: keyof typeof args) => {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(args, s)) {
    return otherFunction(args[s].name);
  } else {
    throw new Error("unknown key: " + s);
  }
}

function otherFunction<T extends keyof typeof args>(s: T[keyof T]) {

}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwOYRgXhgbwFAxgIjnwC4t8w4BbAUxIIEF8BfAGlwICM7NyrbT8AZRA0YAIWZs8%20YN1406%20emAAm8GAGFJ7fCrkUFA5WrgwAItqbxUoSFADc2bLegxKcAJZgAqhGroYAAoIUgBragBPEAAzIKgIgAdqGPhkCABKdPQAPix2D1jAgHkOACtqYCgAOgSEECh6xOoqgAs4CCKAdzAABTqkhHiq4DgAG1HAxBQWGAysnDw8BGooAFcEMBh6luoEADFVsEqPcEm0gG0IAF0qg2p0xzwralG-PMWYKBa6zpgwal%20AFEEHUEIF8IdQmAQN0YOEIgIYABqWYPdhMbAY7DRQ7HcBbL67A5HKAnMAAHgAKjBqAAPKDUVSoeEpeJJFJTCDZYKkSnnFmxSlXeZOJhAA)

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have an object such as:

```
const MyCustomEnum = {
    A: 'value-a',
    B: 'value-b',
    C: 'value-c',
    D: 'value-d',
} as const;
```

### Value-based type

Typescript lets you create types and objects that share the same name. This enables you to create custom object-based enum types, such as:

```
type MyCustomEnum = typeof MyCustomEnum[keyof typeof MyCustomEnum];
```

This will result in the type `MyCustomEnum` being equal to `"value-a" | "value-b" | "value-c" | "value-d"`.

With this, you can use it to set a function's parameter type, as well as use it to pass a value. It works just like the native typescript enums, except a bit more flexible in use. Example:

```
function myFunction(val: MyCustomEnum) {
    // code here
    //able to access the object's values but not keys
}

myFunction(MyCustomEnum.A); // valid
myFunction('value-a');      //also valid
```

---

### Key-based type

You can also do it the other way around, make a type that only accepts the object's key as a valid value. The type declaration would look like this:

```
type MyCustomEnum = keyof typeof MyCustomEnum;
```

This creates a union type like: `"A" | "B" | "C" | "D"`. You can that use it as a function parameter type:

```
function myOtherFunction(key: MyCustomEnum) {
    //code here
    //able to access the object's keys and values
}

myOtherFunction("A"); //valid
myOtherFunction(MyCustomEnum.A); //error
```

---

### Conclusion

The combination of these two solves the majority, if not all const-object-related issues. Hope it helps!

Comment: In your situation both approches may be useful, depending on how you would implement the function.